# How do I display the output of a remote exe locally when using Invoke-Command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script block:

```
$scriptBlock = {Start-Process ping.exe -ArgumentList localhost -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru}
```

Note: I am using a process as I want to be able to set the working directory the exe is executed in.

If I invoke it locally like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

I get the full ping output displayed. But when I invoke it remotely like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

I don't see any of the ping output. How can I get the remote output to display locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `Start-Process` and invoke the command directly:

```
$scriptBlock = {ping.exe localhost}
```

or via the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators):

```
$scriptBlock = {& ping.exe localhost}
```

If you need to run the command from a particular directory, simply change to that directory before running the command:

```
$scriptBlock = {
  Set-Location 'C:\some\folder'
  & ping.exe localhost
}
```

Comment: Ping is just what I use for a test, I need the -WorkingDirectory process flag for the exe I actually want to invoke. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Hawk That doesn't change anything. You can simply set the working directory via `Set-Location` before running the command. See updated answer.